# Laravel concat in query (where condition)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new to laravel and face a problem building a simple query:

```
$query->orWhere("CONCAT(`nvp`, ' ', `vpv`)", 'LIKE', "%$this->searchNeedle%");
```

*This line above is one of several conditions in an encapsulated query condition. I think the other lines are not necessary for this case but tell me if you need to see them.*

I found out that **the developer decided to add** a

> `

before and after the first orWhere/where param which cause the problem that I cant use a simple concat, because the line above will result in:

```
`CONCAT(`vpv`, ' ', `nvp`)` LIKE ?)' 
↑                         ↑
this                    & this
```

Since this is automagically added i cant remove it without overwriting a laravel-core function which i wont. Is there any SQL-based "hack" that handles these two ` ? Something in the way like 1 = 1, you know?

Maybe you have another solution for me to get the intended result, comparing one string with two rows in combination?

Comment: Maybe it works also [iterare where () by request on for loop ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71666425/14664943)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Laravel does some stuff behind the scenes like adding in the tick marks for you.

Fortunately, it also offers a couple of tools to still get the job done for you...

For this type of thing, `DB::raw()` usually works really well.  Try something like this...

```
$query->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(`nvp`, ' ', `vpv`)"), 'LIKE', "%".$this->searchNeedle."%");
```

Comment: Now the App wont crash but result in this: CONCAT(`nvp`, ' ', `vpv`) LIKE '%users name%' is null

Comment: I think my syntax was a little off, I just modified the answer.

Comment: I smell sql injection with this answer,` $this->searchNeedle` is coming directly from the user.

Comment: Laravel will handle the parameter binding for you so no chance of SQL injection.  If the entire thing was wrapped in `DB::raw()` you'd be correct.

Answer (score 20):

Use `orWhereRaw` to execute a raw where query:

```
$query->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(`nvp`, ' ', `vpv`) LIKE ?", ['%'.$this->searchNeedle.'%']);
```

Comment: It doen't work for me (SQL error). I fixed it by putting the `%` into the second argument: `$query->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(nvp, ' ', vpv) LIKE ?", ["%".$this->searchNeedle."%"]);`

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a  Laravel table join related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?

Comment: You must use ` instead of ' for the columns.