# Parse Array to Eloquent\Collection Object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query in Laravel that needed to be upgraded. To get things working fine I had to use

> DB::select(DB::raw());

instead of

> Model::where()->get();

Now the result datatypes differs from the original one which occurs in several errors later in the application.

The simplest way would be to parse the recieved array from $y to look exactly like $x

On the left you see the debugged values on the right (underlined) the used code which the variables result from:

[image: Debug output]

**To keep it simple**: How to get **$y** look like **$x**?

=> Where $y is tagged as {**array**} I need it to be tagged as {**Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection**}

Comment: Since the result differs from $x and $y ($y is the result i have from the new version of the query). I need to parse $y without any use of $x. Look whats in the brackets behind the vars. Where $y is tagged as "{array}" I need it to be tagged as "{Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection}"

Comment: why can't you use `Model::where()->get()` ?

Comment: Because the Laravel developer forgot some cases and adds quotes without checking for the params. Short: Its dirty built by this and it won't work. Another evidence is the different responsetype from two queries by laravel as you can see above.

Comment: Later in the view the application accesses some static methods on the query-result object which are not accessible through an array.

Comment: What do you mean `the Laravel developer forgot some cases`? If you want an Eloquent Collection - then you should call the Model. What are you trying to actually *get*?

Comment: I am not a pro in Laravel but have no choice to modify an application written used Laravel. Is there any possibility of getting the same data-type result from DB::select(DB::raw()) as i get from Model::get() ? Or "parse" the different result type? I guess the debug-picture is pointing out my problem very clear isn't it? Do you need more information? Forget about the query just the result matters in that case.

Comment: You are talking about getting an Eloquent object (from model), vs getting an array (from DB::select()). You havent answered our previous questions - why dont you just call the Model and get whatever data you need as an eloquent model in the first place? What query are you not able to run through the model?

Comment: I answered: Its not possible in that case. I already invested some hours in trying that. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25244611/3048505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (be careful to sql injection)

```
$collection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection(DB::select(DB::raw()));
```

**However,** *Eloquent* and *Query Builder* (*ORM* generally) makes it incredibly easy to interact with a database, so what query exactly are you say "its not possible" with Model?