# How can I convert int to string in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, type-conversion, eloquent

My mysql query is like this :

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, COUNT(*) AS count_store
FROM stores a
JOIN locations b ON CONVERT(b.id,CHAR) = a.address->'$."regency_id"'
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY count_store DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If mysql query I use this : `CONVERT(b.id,CHAR)` to convert int to string

How can I convert int to string in laravel eloquent? I'm using Laravel 5.3.

I had try like this :

```
$stores = Store::select('locations.name','COUNT(*) AS count_store')
               ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'stores.address->regency_id')
               ->groupBy('locations.id')
               ->orderBy('count_store', 'desc')
               ->limit(10)
               ->get();
```

But it does not work

Comment: What did you try?  Can you include your Laravel code?

Comment: Do you want to conver this query to an Eloquent query or do you want to ouptut the field as string?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I had update my question

Comment: @Jerodev, I want to convert to eloquent. See my question. I had update it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a very custom join condition, such as one involving a cast of one or both columns, then I'm not sure this would be possible without at least *some* kind of raw syntax.  Hence, you should consider the answer given by @Rodrane as well as this one:

```
$stores = Store::select('locations.id', 'locations.name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS count_store'))
               ->join('locations', DB::raw("CONVERT(locations.id, CHAR)"), '=', 'stores.address->regency_id')
               ->groupBy('locations.id', 'locations.name')
               ->orderBy('count_store', 'desc')
               ->limit(10)
               ->get();
```

Note that I made the following changes:

- Used `DB::raw()` to give a custom alias to the count
- Added `location.name` to the `GROUP BY` (and select) clause
- Used another `DB::raw()` to handle the cast in the join condition

Comment: @BenOfTheNorth I went with your suggestion but I could find no example of this syntax anywhere.  If you have a link that would be appreciated.

Comment: Ha I deleted the comment as you'd updated - I use it daily, it's correct syntax - take a look through https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries and you'll see a few examples of DB::Raw in use as a replacement for a regular param.

Comment: Aha...but the documentation doesn't actually show using `DB::raw()` as a join parameter, but nevertheless it is valid.  They should update their documentation which seems to imply using a separate closure for more complex joins.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, There exist error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(*)' in 'field list`

Answer (score 0):

More simply, we start from an initial query, for this case we create the where conditions in a loop, which, based on each request field that we add, another condition ->where is added to the query.

```
 $query = DB::table($type)->select('*'); //or $query = Model::select();
    if ($request) {
        foreach ($request->request as $key => $value) {
            $query = $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $query->get();// or $query->get();
```

use $query->toSql() si desea la query como string ...