# How to Use "CONCAT" in laravel where clause without using model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, concatenation

I have a table ('mbo_party') where has two column first and last (I have used first to store firstname, last to store lastname). Suppose I store Debanjan in column 'first' and Ganguly in 'last'. So in search field if one search by 'Debanjan Ganguly', how do I get all the data from that column. I am using laravel 5.4, I am not using any model. I write query in my controller. Here's my code so far...

**Controller**

```
    $party_name = $request->get('party_name');
        $query = DB::table('mbo_party')->where('concat(first," ",last)' , '=' , $party_name)->first();
```

**View**

```
    <form id="party_search_it" method="GET" action="{{route('mbo-index')}}"> 
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="party_name" placeholder="Search for Party Name..." autocomplete="off">
    </form>
```

**My Table View**
[Here's my Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oEpG.png)

In this method when I am using echo in controller , it is showing blank.

```
    echo"<pre>";print_r($query);die;
```

I want to know what is correct syntax for performing this kind of operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel concat in query (where condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244317/laravel-concat-in-query-where-condition)

Comment: no, I want to use it via DB::table('mbo_party')->where() method, without using model, want to know correct syntax for this.

Comment: DB::raw in where() is the key here man. Same question, different methods, same solution.

Comment: how to know which table I am using then ??

Comment: $query = DB::table('mbo_party')->where(DB::raw('concat(first," ",last)') , '=' , $party_name)->first(); Just like Sunil kumawat anwser and the same solution as the duplicate page... He uses LIKE instead of =, that's the only diff. Tested on my laravel install (changed table name and columns to match mine though) but works. Why don't you try dd($query) on the line after to see exactly what is returned?

Comment: Thanks Ross, thats worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$query = DB::table('mbo_party')->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first,' ',last)"), 'LIKE', '%' . $party_name . '%')->first();
```

Comment: What did you change? `("CONCAT(first," ` looks like invalid PHP.

Comment: It is Showing  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '",last)"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: It doesn't showing any error, but on doing echo, $query isn't returning any value, I mean to say    echo"<pre>";print_r($query);die; showing blank page

Comment: Welcome @iamawesome

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$query = DB::table('mbo_party')->whereRaw('CONCAT(`first`," ",`last`) = "' . $party_name . '"'))->first();
```